# Slow SQL query when dataset increase

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm doing a SQL query on my database to get all the players the desired player plays the most with (in the same `match_players.team`).

It's going great but when the player has more than 5000 matches (that's where I found the issue), the query can takes 10 to 20 seconds. I was wondering if it was possible to optimise it.

I'm using PostgreSQL (12.16).

Here are my tables, I've removed all the unused fields for this query.

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.match_players (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    match_id character varying(15) NOT NULL,
    summoner_puuid character varying(78) NOT NULL,
    summoner_name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    win smallint NOT NULL,
    loss smallint NOT NULL,
    remake smallint NOT NULL,
    team smallint NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE public.match_players_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE public.match_players_id_seq OWNED BY public.match_players.id;

CREATE TABLE public.matches (
    id character varying(15) NOT NULL,
    gamemode smallint NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.match_players ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public.match_players_id_seq'::regclass);

-- PK
ALTER TABLE ONLY public.match_players
    ADD CONSTRAINT match_players_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.matches
    ADD CONSTRAINT matches_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

-- INDEXES
CREATE INDEX match_players_summoner_puuid_index ON public.match_players USING btree (summoner_puuid);
CREATE INDEX match_players_team_index ON public.match_players USING btree (team);
CREATE INDEX matches_gamemode_index ON public.matches USING btree (gamemode);
```

Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT
    (array_agg(mates.summoner_name ORDER BY mates.match_id DESC)) [1] AS name,
    COUNT(match_players.id) AS count,
    SUM(match_players.win) AS wins,
    SUM(match_players.loss) AS losses
FROM
    match_players
    INNER JOIN matches ON matches.id = match_players.match_id
    INNER JOIN match_players AS mates ON match_players.match_id = mates.match_id
        AND match_players.team = mates.team
WHERE
    match_players.summoner_puuid = 'wBdgONoUnYZCPbh8jp9d47XL6gv9Fj4W8KugWh_Nr9FLESnT9zhGix2hliOPOxNmuhoI1v3gYk4BXA'
    AND match_players.remake = 0
    AND matches.gamemode NOT IN(800, 810, 820, 830, 840, 850, 2000, 2010, 2020)
GROUP BY
    mates.summoner_puuid
ORDER BY
    count DESC,
    wins DESC
LIMIT 15
```

And here is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the query:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=726349.74..726349.78 rows=15 width=134) (actual time=17124.387..17124.689 rows=15 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=726349.74..726451.94 rows=40880 width=134) (actual time=16659.572..16659.866 rows=15 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (count(match_players.id)) DESC, (sum(match_players.win)) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 29kB
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=724222.58..725346.78 rows=40880 width=134) (actual time=16567.953..16651.876 rows=18835 loops=1)
              Group Key: mates.summoner_puuid
              ->  Sort  (cost=724222.58..724324.78 rows=40880 width=111) (actual time=16567.899..16582.073 rows=28215 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: mates.summoner_puuid
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3448kB
                    ->  Gather  (cost=53749.23..718714.85 rows=40880 width=111) (actual time=1267.589..16496.245 rows=28215 loops=1)
                          Workers Planned: 2
                          Workers Launched: 2
                          ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=52749.23..713626.85 rows=17033 width=111) (actual time=1142.845..16434.330 rows=9405 loops=3)
                                Hash Cond: (((mates.match_id)::text = (matches.id)::text) AND (mates.team = match_players.team))
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on match_players mates  (cost=0.00..622960.94 rows=5046094 width=105) (actual time=0.397..13551.825 rows=4037261 loops=3)
                                ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=52698.13..52698.13 rows=3407 width=40) (actual time=978.287..978.291 rows=1881 loops=3)
                                      Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 576kB
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=638.66..52698.13 rows=3407 width=40) (actual time=634.953..686.920 rows=1881 loops=3)
                                            ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on match_players  (cost=638.23..31290.55 rows=3488 width=25) (actual time=634.871..646.260 rows=1883 loops=3)
                                                  Recheck Cond: ((summoner_puuid)::text = 'wBdgONoUnYZCPbh8jp9d47XL6gv9Fj4W8KugWh_Nr9FLESnT9zhGix2hliOPOxNmuhoI1v3gYk4BXA'::text)
                                                  Filter: (remake = 0)
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 27
                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=3367
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on match_players_summoner_puuid_index  (cost=0.00..636.14 rows=8477 width=0) (actual time=0.699..0.700 rows=5730 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: ((summoner_puuid)::text = 'wBdgONoUnYZCPbh8jp9d47XL6gv9Fj4W8KugWh_Nr9FLESnT9zhGix2hliOPOxNmuhoI1v3gYk4BXA'::text)
                                            ->  Index Scan using matches_pkey on matches  (cost=0.43..6.14 rows=1 width=15) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=5649)
                                                  Index Cond: ((id)::text = (match_players.match_id)::text)
                                                  Filter: (gamemode <> ALL ('{800,810,820,830,840,850,2000,2010,2020}'::integer[]))
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 0
Planning Time: 0.903 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 78
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 17.883 ms, Inlining 385.880 ms, Optimization 1308.476 ms, Emission 672.236 ms, Total 2384.476 ms
Execution Time: 17129.121 ms
```

Graphical version of the explain: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/27b41c259g9d3483

Interactive example to play with it: https://dbfiddle.uk/TcErJ6WL

Thanks a lot if you have any idea, I don't really know where to look at anymore.

**EDIT - Solution thanks to @LSerni and @MatBailie comments**

I added three combined indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX match_players_combined_index1 ON match_players (summoner_puuid, remake, match_id);
CREATE INDEX match_players_combined_index2 ON match_players (match_id, team, summoner_puuid, summoner_name);
CREATE INDEX matches_combined_index1 ON matches (id, gamemode);
```

And I've removed the `NOT IN` and the `array_agg` from the query:

```
SELECT
    (
    SELECT
      summoner_name
    FROM
      match_players
    WHERE
      summoner_puuid = mates.summoner_puuid
    ORDER BY
      match_id DESC
    LIMIT
      1
    ) AS name,
    COUNT(match_players.id) AS count,
    SUM(match_players.win) AS wins,
    SUM(match_players.loss) AS losses
FROM
    match_players
    INNER JOIN matches ON matches.id = match_players.match_id
    INNER JOIN match_players AS mates ON match_players.match_id = mates.match_id
        AND match_players.team = mates.team
WHERE
    match_players.summoner_puuid = 'wBdgONoUnYZCPbh8jp9d47XL6gv9Fj4W8KugWh_Nr9FLESnT9zhGix2hliOPOxNmuhoI1v3gYk4BXA'
    AND match_players.remake = 0
    AND (
    (matches.gamemode < 800 OR matches.gamemode > 899)
    AND
    (matches.gamemode < 2000 OR matches.gamemode > 2999)
)
GROUP BY
    mates.summoner_puuid
ORDER BY
    count DESC,
    wins DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Now the query takes 300-700ms, which is really better!

Comment: try to make combined indexes with all column in ON and WHERE clause,

Comment: Please don’t link to external websites - all questions should be self-contained. Add the explain plan to your question as editable text

Comment: @NickW sorry for that, updating right now!

Comment: @nbk As I'm using 2 different tables, how can I do that? 2 different combined indexes?

Comment: you can combine two tables columns in an index you take all column for one table and make a index in that table

Comment: Why are you using array aggregation and picking the first name? That will be relatively expensive if a player has played many games... Why not just `GROUP BY summoner_name` and SELECT it directly? https://dbfiddle.uk/7J_RNo47 *(fiddle includes your fiddle, example compound indexes, and query grouping by the name)*

Comment: @MatBailie I'm using the `summoner_puuid` because players can change their `summoner_name` and I'm displaying their latest, I don't know if I can do it more easily. Thanks for the indexes examples!

Comment: Using those three indexes (as opposed to your two) should speed it up even further, even with the array_agg()[1]

Comment: Also, what if the player changes their name after their last match with PlayerX?

Comment: @MatBailie it works indeed better with the 3 indexes, thanks a lot! I've updated my question with these. It's a good concern for the names, I think I'll stay with the lesser evil which is the current solution. Otherwise, I would have to do one addition request per player to get their actual name which would be too slow for my use-case.

Comment: I doubt it would be too slow... https://dbfiddle.uk/VgUlneDp

Comment: @MatBailie Oh yes you are right this is better! I was thinking about another issue: maybe I don't have the actual new player name is my database yet, therefore I have to do one more request. But it's not relevant at all here. Thanks!

Comment: I also suggest stop using character datatypes for ids. Use integers or similar, even if your base/dimension tables need the character keys (natural key) they vs also have integer keys (surrogate key) for use in joining tables, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check this query out:

> ```
> SELECT
>     (array_agg(mates.summoner_name ORDER BY mates.match_id DESC)) [1] AS name,
>     COUNT(match_players.id) AS count,
>     SUM(match_players.win) AS wins,
>     SUM(match_players.loss) AS losses
> FROM
>     match_players
>     INNER JOIN matches ON matches.id = match_players.match_id
>     INNER JOIN match_players AS mates ON match_players.match_id = mates.match_id
>         AND match_players.team = mates.team
> WHERE
>     match_players.summoner_puuid = 'wBdgONoUnYZCPbh8jp9d47XL6gv9Fj4W8KugWh_Nr9FLESnT9zhGix2hliOPOxNmuhoI1v3gYk4BXA'
>     AND match_players.remake = 0
>     AND matches.gamemode NOT IN(800, 810, 820, 830, 840, 850, 2000, 2010, 2020)
> GROUP BY
>     mates.summoner_puuid
> ORDER BY
>     count DESC,
>     wins DESC
> LIMIT 15
> ```

So, we want an index targeting the fixed WHERE conditions, and possibly with an easy condition first. So our index for `match_players` should start with **two** columns: remake and summoner_puuid.

The index efficacy lies in *how few* rows it can limit the selection - how selective it is. So if most values of "remake" were 0, having remake in first position would avail little. On the other hand, integer comparisons are in general faster than string comparisons. So, whether remake goes first or second position is a matter for experiment.

Now, what more do we need from match_players? The JOIN uses `match_id`. We ought to put that in the index, in third position.

For the same reason we need 'team'. If the table is large we might gain something adding also win and loss, but maybe not. More experiments to make.

```
CREATE INDEX match_players_ndx1 ON match_players (summoner_puuid, remake, match_id, team);
```

With these four index columns the RDBMS can run the WHERE and get match_id and team, *without ever touching the table*, and can then go on with the other joins.

To this effect, we need an index on matches using id that also supplies gamemode (the condition on gamemode is terrible though. NOT IN is a performance nightmare. If you only could rewrite it as BETWEEN or suchlike...).

```
CREATE INDEX matches_ndx1 ON matches (id, gamemode);
```

We also need an index on match_id on the mates table, and this index should also hold mates.team. It *might* hold summoner_name but again, this might not be worth it. You can experiment.

```
CREATE INDEX mates_ndx1 ON mates (match_id, team);
```

With this indexing (or improvements thereof) the RDBMS ought to be able to quickly and efficiently "zero in" on the needed data.

Comment: You go to long lengths to describe compound indexes, but never show them (the op may not know they can be done, or how). Please actually include the relevant CREATE INDEX statements.

Comment: I have updated my question with your solution. Actually if I used remake at the beginning of the index, the perf were bad (because a very very small portions of the matches are remake I think). So I used another order and it looks like it's working well! Thanks!

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks, you're right - and I had also forgotten to consider the cardinality of the index, which is why Kalane had to invert remake and puuid in the index. Added code and warnings to the answer.